# ViewController Transition xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin.ios, transition, viewcontroller

I'm developing the swipe animation to go back in the storyboards, the classic animation of ios that allows you to go back browsing the GUI ... I wrote this code, the gesture works and also the action but everything happens statically because the transition animation is missing, how can I enable it? plz ... thanks

```
//gesture comeback
var BackGesture = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(swipe);
BackGesture.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
BackGesture.NumberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
View.AddGestureRecognizer(BackGesture);
//evento comeback
void swipe(UISwipeGestureRecognizer sw1){
    //comeback
    apriStoryBoard("Home");
}
```

Comment: You have to implement the swipe transition animation by yourself.

Comment: Yes, but how i can do this? i'm not found nothing online..

Comment: Here is the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html) you can read and refer.

Comment: No problem, hope it help you and you can share your solution here once you find one:).